# Serve static files in Django. Need explanation

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I  want to know which way is correct to serve static files in `Django`. All are working but which one is the best way.

I have tried `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in my templates. Which is working fine.

And then `{% load static %}` and used `{% static 'path/to/static/file' %}` to load static file.
And this one is also working.
`{% load staticfiles %}` and then `{% static 'path/to/static/file' %}` for loading static file.

I am confused which one is the correct and should be used. Please can someone explain it to me.
As far as i know `{{ STATIC_URL }}` tag just uses the `STATIC_URL` defined in `settings.py` file.

But what does `load static` and `load staticfiles` does behind the scenes. I have tried the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/) and this [one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#static)

Comment: Otherwise simply `{{ STATIC_URL }}` and can you please explain me about `load staic/staticfiles`

Comment: Got my answer ... `load static` will provide `STATIC_URL` regardless  RequestContext is provided or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any plan to use an alternative storage (for example using [`django-stroage`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-storages)), you should use `{% static ... %}` tag.

[`static`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static) tag ask storage backend to return `url`.

For default storage [`FileSystemStorage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/storage/#the-filesystemstorage-class), `static` returns just `settings.STAITC_URL` joined with the request file name.

---

[`load`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#load) loads custom tags, filters. To use `static`, you need to load it because it is not part of libraries that is loaded by default.

Comment: @user2217267, About `load staticfiles`,  read a Note in [`static` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static). In short, you need to use `staticfiles` if you want to use another backend storage backend.